# SQL moving average by weekday with moving range for last 4 weeks, excluding current week

Tags: sql, teradata

I'm trying to calculate 7 day moving average by weekday, for last 4 weeks but not including the current week.   The code below calculates the average however that includes the current week's data.   How can I exclude the current week and only calculate last 4 Sundays, Mondays, Tuesdays, etc.   Please note, the average will differ by day.  For example, each Sunday will have a different average based on the last 4 weeks.

Attached is the sample data and desired results [Data example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hD9DF.jpg)

```
Select a.Date, a.WeekDay, 
   avg(a.count) Over(partition by a.WeekDay order by a.Date rows between 3 preceding and current row) as rolling_avg

from

(Select Date, WeekDay, Count from Sales) a

Where a.Date >= current_date- 7*7
```

Comment: Please provide sample data and desired results.

Comment: I included sample data and desired results

Comment: Is there a row for every date in the input data, even if count is zero? Please supply sample data / results as text not image.

Answer (score 1):

You almost have it, change the way to use following ROWS. You need to use FOLLOWING 1 to use starting next row and 4 as the limit. I also changed the order by date desc that, way the next row is the previous week.

```
Select 
  a.Date_V, 
  a.WeekDay, 
  --AVG(CAST(a.count_v AS DECIMAL(8,2))) OVER /*cast optional*/
  AVG(a.count_v) Over
  (partition by a.WeekDay order by  a.date_v desc  
  ROWS BETWEEN 1 FOLLOWING AND 4 FOLLOWING) as rolling_avg
FROM

  (Select Date_V, WeekDay, Count_v from historic_data) a

Where a.Date_v >= GETDATE()- 7*7
ORDER BY a.date_v desc
```

I created following [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/b1bfc/16) for testing if someone wants to play with it.